# Is it possible to use browser->drag() from dusk with Vuedraggable?

Tags: vue.js, laravel-dusk

We are using [VueDraggable](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable) (and Vue) in our front-end and we are testing our front-end with Dusk.

I am currently trying to use [$browser->drag('selector', 'selector')](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/dusk#using-the-mouse) from dusk to drag objects from one list to the other, but I don't see anything happening during the test (although it might be the action is not visible) nor is the right result shown, the object does not end up in the indicated list.

I was wondering if anybody made a working example already of using $browser->drag() combined with Vue.draggable? I am asking since I don't know if I am trying the impossible or not.

Answer (score 0):

There is an open issue for this on Dusk's Github. I had to open a new issue [that can be found here](https://github.com/laravel/dusk/issues/308) since the original was closed for comment. The link contains a more thorough explanation, but the short answer and solution are highlighted here:

*Problem*: Laravel's Dusk does not trigger Vue.draggable events. To simulate a drag-and-drop Dusk does a "mouse down", "move mouse to location", and "mouse up" sequence. In theory this is correct but does not trigger Vue' s events.

*Solution*: Dusk's method does trigger mouse down and mouse up events, so we can simply use those events to trigger the ones desired.

```
$("a[draggable='true']").on("mousedown", function(event)  {
    $(this).trigger("dragstart");
});

$("div[droppable='true']").on("mouseup", function(event) {
    $(this).trigger("drop");
});
```

[This JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/grantdscs/nehjrbzo/) is an example of how it would work (though you need to implement it on a Laravel project to truly test, of course!).

Comment: Isaiah, have you been able to get this working with the VueDraggable extension? I'm now able to simulate some of the drag/drop functionality of plain libraries, but my VueDraggable lists are chaining a lot of events (choose, clone, start, input, change, update, sort, end) and trying to bind these to a mousedown trigger doesn't give results for me.

Comment: Sorry, but unfortunately not. This was as far as I needed to go at the time and I climbed right back into my backend cave shortly after :). Are you also attempting to interface VueDraggable with Dusk? Are you able to get VueDraggable to work independently? If so, how I was able to resolve my issue was drill down into Dusk and derive what it was _trying_ to do and that showed me where the disconnect was and what I needed to do interface the two.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply! I have a pretty complex sequence of events because I'm dragging things from one list to another, cloning and rendering the items. I did get Dusk to do some dragging, but it doesn't obey Draggable rules anymore and drags inside of a div container into no-mans-land. Attempting to emit the events through Javascript doesn't seem to do the trick either... I guess I'll have to just trust the unit-tests for this specific interaction.